# Installation error: "E:Unable to locate package ros-groovy"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the full desktop version of ros on ubuntu 12.04, but I'm getting two errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
mdegges@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy
E: Unable to locate package desktop-full**
```

I'm new to linux & ros, so not sure how to proceed from here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56039/installation-error:-%22e:unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy%22/) by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

Note the dash between groovy and desktop.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-02-22**:
heh, I realized I had missed the dash right before you posted. sorry for the lame question.